# Double quote in C# string

Tags: c#, string

I want to add double quote in c# string.

```
string searchString = "123";
string inputString = "No matches found for "+ "\""+searchString + "\"";
```

OutPut: `No matches found for "123"`

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Can you give some more details? From the question, it looks like you have already got what you need.

Comment: Your code does that already, albeit with one unnecessary string concatenation (you can use `string inputString = "No matches found for \"" + searchString + "\"";`).

Comment: There are double quotes on 123, only you cant see that if you are using debugger to see inputString's value. Try `Console.WriteLine(inputString);` you get your desired OutPut... so all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should produce what your expecting:

`No matches found for "123"`

You could also try:

```
string searchString = "123";
string inputString = String.Format(@"No matches found for ""{0}""!", searchString);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need `string.format`.

For example:

```
string.format("No matches found for \"{0}\"", searchString);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
string inputString = String.Format(@"No matches found for \"{0}\"", searchString);
```

Comment: This won't even compile! Proper escape for double quote in a verbatim string is "" (twice the double quote), so it would become String.Format(@"No matches found for ""{0}""", searchString);

Comment: To the above comment: Why not just say that the at-sign should be removed?

Comment: @jgauffin, :) down-voting is power! :)